# Відмінювання власних назв

Tags: відмінювання

Так і не знайшов в чинному правописі вказівок щодо відмінювання назв творів. Тож, як правильно сказати:

- Настя прочитала "Злочин і кару".
- Настя прочитала "Злочин і кара".

Comment: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прикладка